# Getting mass-assignment warning in rails 3.1.8, but no attr_accessible called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

I have a standalone app that runs on Rails 3.0.7, that is also used as a rails engine, which is run under rails 3.1.8 from the parent app. Now, I have a registration form which connects to a user model, has validations and so forth. When I was running the app as an engine, and I would try to register, I could see in the logs a "cannot mass-assign attributes" warning.

My user.rb model file has no calls to `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected`. Adding a call to `attr_accessible` for the given fields on that model fixed the issue. However, I am wondering what might be causing it. When I run the app as standalone, it works fine. I'm not sure if the rails version has anything to do with it, but it's an important difference to note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if parent projects config/environments/x.rb file has config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict, if so commenting it may work but not advisable

Comment: Looks like it is in the environments/test.rb file, but not development. I double checked my virtualhost file, and the environment is setup to run in development.

Comment: Oh hello, the application.rb file has: `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`, that would do it. I'll accept your answer since you led me to it :)